# fragment automatically refreshed in viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-viewpager

I have viewpager with 4 tabs, and using fragments in each tabs. And i have webview in each fragment. when I was in the first tab there are no mistakes, until the third tab. When i back to first tab, fragment refresh automatic. It make webview loadUrl() again. I don't want it. How to stop that refresh ?

Another explain:
I have 4 tabs. I call it, Tab AA, BB, CC, and DD with adjacent. When I in Tab AA and go to Tab BB, there are no mistakes. But when I in Tab AA go to CC and go back to tab AA, the fragment in tab AA refresh again. And i want to know explanation about  lifecycle in viewpager ? Thanks..

Comment: Set the off screen page limit to 4. like `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);`. Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

you can use setOffscreenPageLimit to set the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the current page in the view hierarchy in an idle state. Pages beyond this limit will be recreated from the adapter when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the [ViewPager Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int)). The default behaviour is to retain 1 page either side of what's currently displayed. You can change it using `setOffscreenPageLimit (int limit)`

Answer (score 0):

just use

viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);